# Unsure of my mistake in CS50 Half practice problem

Tags: c, cs50

Here's the background:
"Suppose you are eating out at a restaurant with a friend and want to split the bill evenly. You may want to anticipate the amount you’ll owe before the bill arrives with tax added. In this problem, you’ll complete a function to calculate the amount each of you owes based on the bill amount, the tax, and the tip.

The tax should be added to the bill amount before calculating the tip."

I wrote the code below:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    tax = (tax * 0.01 * bill);
    tip = (tip * 0.01 * (bill + tax));
    float half = ((bill + tip + tax)/2.0);
    return half;
}
```

An example of correct output would be:
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sale Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
You will owe $8.17 each!

However, with said inputs, I end up with $7.80 each. This is the only practice problem I can't figure out what I've been doing wrong, so I'd appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Do not post to Stack Overflow without working to debug your program first. Use a debugger or insert `printf` statements to view the values of `tax`, `tip`, and `half` as soon as they are calculated. What do you see for their values? What should you see for their values? Which one is wrong? Why is it wrong?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: This assignment is from week 1 of CS50, but unfortunately, OP will only learn in week 2 of CS50 how to use a debugger.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Hence “or insert `printf` statements.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Apologies, I'd tried debugging earlier but I thought it was fine, I've figured the issue out after a second round of debugging! My mistake was that the 'tip' defined in my function still remained as an int when it should've been a float instead - silly small mistake. Thank you

Comment: The `tip` in the function is an `int` — you should probably be using a `float`.  Why stop people fromgiving a 17.5% tip?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Because it is in the problem statement: “you’ll complete a function”. The student is given most of the code and is only supposed to complete a function.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: As stated in the question, OP is given code to complete. The types are not their choice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair point, although OP does use `double` math with those `double` constants.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: but the assignment to the integer tip loses a lot of the calculated value, which just exacerbates the unfairness of the tip system.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The parameter is an `int`. The assignment is to complete the function, so the `int tip` parameter is likely fixed and cannot be changed. Assigning the calculation of the tip to `tip` instead of to some `float` variable is an error. Fairness or unfairness is not part of the assignment and is irrelevant.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Could I clarify some points mentioned? Firstly, when are floats 'truly needed'? When RAM/storage is low? Secondly, what makes tax * 0.01 * bill a double calculation? And wrt the 7th point, wouldn't putting it in cents make the numbers inconveniently big if we were working with large monetary amounts?

Comment: `floats` are typically needed when 1) large arrays of FP needed w/o much precision or range  2) Embedded applications severely processor constrained.  `tax * 0.01 * bill` is a `double` calculation because `0.01` is a `double` and so the other objects (`tax`, `bill`)  are converted to `double` prior to the `double` multiplication.  Note that `printf("... $%.2f each!\n", half(...));` causes the `float` result of `half()` to convert to a `double`.  As cents, `long long` easily handles hundreds of years of the US budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP has insight to the [basic trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75842004/unsure-of-my-mistake-in-cs50-half-practice-problem#comment133779154_75842004).

Some other issues:

- In C, avoid `float` unless truly needed.  Best to default to `double`.
- Note that `tax * 0.01 * bill` is a `double` calculation.  To only use `float` math use `tax * 0.01f * bill`.
- Better to work *money* using whole numbers.  Consider scaling to the least monetary unit.  For this code 0.01 is sufficient.
- Be prepared to handle the split of an odd final sum.
- Is the tip based on pre-tax or post-tax?  (Post-tax is more common.)
- Tax calculation driven by a percentage here, yet the rounding details are a matter of tax law.  Let us assume rounding to the nearest integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero.
- With each money item, like `bill, tax amount, tip, sum`, best to ensure each is a whole number value (in cents).
- Consider crisper names.  `tax` is usually an amount of *money*.  `tax_rate` or `tax_percentage` is a better term for what OP calls *tax*.  Use of such names may well have prevented OP's mistake in the first place.  `float tax = (tax_percentage * 0.01 * bill);`

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax_percentage, int tip_percentage) {
    // Convert money into nearest cent
    long long ibill = llround(bill * 100.0);
    long long itax = llround(ibill * (tax_percentage/100.0));
    long long isum = ibill + itax;
    long long itip = llround(isum * (tip_percentage/100.0));
    long long ibottom_line = isum + itip;
    ibottom_line += ibottom_line % 2;  // Provide extra 0.01 tip when odd.
    // Divide by 2 to split the bill and then convert back to $
    return (ibottom_line/2)/100.0f;
}
```

Notice calculations involving percentages use floating point math.

Money addition uses integer math - no round-off errors.

Answer (score 0):

As I was working on illustrating the issue of the tip value being an integer value in the calculations, I see that someone has already made a good comment about the issue.  However, I will illustrate what is going on with the issue of using the tip variable in your tip calculation.

Following is a bit of refactored code for your "half" function with some added printf statements to illustrate what is happening.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    tax = (tax * 0.01 * bill);
    printf("Tax: %.2f\n", tax);
    tip = (tip * 0.01 * (bill + tax));
    printf("Tip: %d\n", tip);
    float half = ((bill + tip + tax)/2.0);
    return half;
}
```

Executing your program with this extra bit of information, it can be seen that the tip about is having any fractional portion of the tip truncated, and so understates the amount to be split.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/SplitBill/bin/Release$ ./SplitBill 
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sales Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
Tax: 1.109375
Tip: 2
You will owe $7.80 each!
```

Refactoring the function to utilize a floating point variable to calculate the tip, the expected split amount is calculated.

```
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tipx = tip;
    tax = (tax * 0.01 * bill);
    printf("Tax: %.2f\n", tax);
    tipx = (tipx * 0.01 * (bill + tax));
    printf("Tip: %.2f\n", tipx);
    float half = ((bill + tipx + tax)/2.0);
    return half;
}
```

Here is the terminal output with this refactored bit.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/SplitBill/bin/Release$ ./SplitBill 
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sales Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
Tax: 1.11
Tip: 2.72
You will owe $8.17 each!
```

So, the bottom line is that one needs to be careful and cognizant of how integers behave in calculations.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.