# Harvard CS50 Half Program: float half(float bill, float tax, float tip) function

Tags: c, cs50

I am very new to programming, and I am having trouble understanding this program. The assignment asks to calculate the total bill (when given bill amount, tax percent, and tip percent) and then divide it to calculate someone's half of the bill. The following code is correct and produces the desired outcome, I am just having trouble understanding how it works.

The function "float half(float bill, float tax, float tip)" (half1) is used to calculate the half of the bill. I understand it pulls the values from "half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent)" (half2). However, I am struggling to wrap my head around how this works.

How does half1 pull the numbers from half2, if half2 comes before it in the main function?

Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
// Calculate your half of a restaurant bill
// Data types, operations, type casting, return value

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, float tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    float tip_percent = get_float("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, float tip)
{
    float total_amount = bill + (bill * (tax / 100));
    total_amount += total_amount * (tip / 100);
    return total_amount / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Hi please read through [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [why-should-i-not-upload-images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/) Posting images of code will almost always result in quick downvotes because good questions should not contain images of code.

Comment: `(float bill, float tax, float tip)` is the parameter list that indicates the types and names of the function's parameters.

Comment: If it is not correct, please add the inputs, the expected output, and your actual output by editing the question.

Comment: @topsail apologies! Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: This question is for the same issue as raised back in March by another user.  You might want to view this link for possible answers "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75842004/unsure-of-my-mistake-in-cs50-half-practice-problem/75842500#75842500".

Answer (score 0):

the first time the word *half* appears, on top, just below the include statements, is the function **declaration** (1). All this is supposed to do, is to tell the compiler, hey don't panic, there will be a function called *half*, returning a float and taking 3 float arguments.
When the program reaches the second appearance of *half* in the printf statement at the end of the main function, the compiler knows what to expect. What is done here is called a function **call**. You could say, your program is *using* the function. So it tells the computer to actually execute the routine you define in *half*. For it to be able to do so, the function has to be declared above it, which it is (see(1)). So we are good here.

The third time *half* appears, just below the TODO, is the function **definition**. You could say this is the actual function (not very accurate but close enough for now :)). The routine of what to do when the function is called, is written here. Every time you call *half* the code between the curly braces is executed, with the parameter variables filled with the values assigned to them in the function call (the values in the parentheses).

So it's less that the function definition *pulls* it's values from somewhere but more that the function call is telling the computer to execute the function code while substituting the parameter variables with the values of the call. Imagine you work as a waiter in a restaurant and you come to the kitchen and *call* the cook to *cook* what the customer ordered like this: `cook(chickenburger, large fries)`.
The cook could have a cook function like the following:

```
    dishes cook(char *order1, char *order2) {
        // magical kitchen stuff
        // ...
        return cooked_dishes;
    }
```

Did that help a little? Have fun with CS50!

Comment: A _waiter_ AND a _cook_... The analogy describes multiple (parallel) processes...

Comment: I wanted to visualize why someone else (or some other function) calls a function and why it's not the other way around as this seemed to  confuse them. This is not intended to be an actual project.

Comment: It might be easier for a beginner to understand the waiter seating patrons, delivering menus, taking orders, delivering meals, taking payment and clearing the table as the suite of _functions_ to be timed and executed appropriately as patrons (data) arrive, linger, and depart. One waiter; one thread of execution.